# Sending multipart file after modified it via javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, multipartform-data

I am building a JSP + AngularJS + HTML5 front-end and have the following situation:

1. Upload a zip file.
2. Using the zip.js library to open it, modify some content and close it (actually is creating a new one).

Reading I have found that input files are not editable due to security reasons.

Using form-data and ajax I am able to send it but the requirement is to send it with the normal submit JSP button but is not working this way (being null the multipart at server side).

Is it posible to send the modified HPUB via JSP submit?

Comment: Why would you want to modify a zipfile on the client-side before uploading to the server?

Comment: I cannot say it because of a NDA...but I need it, sorry.

Comment: It seems to me it would make more sense to add whatever it is to the zipfile once it gets to the server.